# When i change the size of placeholder in textbox it looks wrong

Tags: css, textbox, placeholder

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s636q7xh/)
The problem is in the placeholder, when i make the font-size higher it looks wrong, check the jsfiddle, the text looks split in half.

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" />

#txtSearch {

    width:1050px;

    height:35px;

    background-color:#605784;

    border-width:0px;

}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {

    color: White;

    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;

    font-size:15pt;

    position:relative;

    top:-5px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[checkout this solution from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916387/placeholder-font-size-bigger-than-16px)**The input and its placeholder must have matching font styles**

```
    input,
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {

    color: White;

    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;

    font-size:15pt;

    position:relative;

    top:-5px;

}
```