# Does replacing a form input's outline with box-shadow violate any WCAG guidelines?

Tags: html, css, forms, accessibility, wcag

**Question**

What accessibility downsides are there to set `outline` to `none` and instead use `box-shadow` to highlight an active input? Does it violate WCAG at all?

**Background**

User agent style sheets highlight an active element's `outline` on focus. To customize this highlighting we can use the `:focus` selector. This works well for rectangular shaped input elements, but doesn't look good on rounded inputs. A mismatching square is displayed. See below example where the red outline is square even though the input has rounded corners.

[image: Red, square outline around input box with rounded corners]

As `outline` is rectangular, to better match a rounded element, an alternative way to style is to replace `outline` with `box-shadow`. This require setting `outline: none`, which [seems controversial](http://www.outlinenone.com/) from an accessibility perspective.

**Example**

```css
input {
  border-radius: 999em;
  padding: 10px;
}

.outline:focus {
  outline: solid 15px red;
}

.box-shadow:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px red;
}
```

```html
<label for="with-outline">Outline</label>
<input name="with-outline" id="with-outline" class="outline">
<hr>
<label for="with-box-shadow">Box Shadow</label>
<input name="with-box-shadow" id="with-box-shadow" class="box-shadow">
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Since the focus is clearly showing something then it's fine (it doesn't really matter if it's rectangular or circular)

Comment: @George: Thank you for pointing out that the question was unclear. Restructured the whole post.

Comment: I'm hoping the topic is clearer now after an edit.
The intention was to discuss box-shadow vs outline. Whole web sites are made to explain how cancelling outline is an antipattern; http://www.outlinenone.com/.

Comment: I've further edited this question and title to specify an objective specification for accessibility. Without such a metric, the question would ultimately be opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

No issues with using `box-shadow` or `outline` if you don't need to support IE8. There are a few considerations such as colour contrast but technically your current example passes current guidance (although I would encourage you to increase the colour contrast slightly).

### Longer Answer

The main thing you need to consider is colour contrast. As long as the border is a 3:1 contrast ratio with the background then under current guidance you are OK.

However WCAG 2.2 comes into effect from June / July 2021 so you may as well prepare for that.

#### WCAG 2.2

As long as you have sufficient contrast and it is **thick enough** to comply with WCAG 2.2 (so you don't have to redo stuff when that comes into effect) you will be fine. The following is a summary of the upcoming rule changes (which the example you gave passes):

**Change of contrast:** The colour change for the focus indication area has a contrast ratio of at least 3:1 with the colours of the unfocused state.

The following is *IN ADDITION* to the above:

> **Contrast or thickness:** The focus indication area has a 3:1 contrast ratio against all adjacent colours for the minimum area or greater, or has a thickness of at least 2 CSS pixels.

The focus needs a minimum 3:1 *change* and also needs to be:

- either 2px thick and/or
- 3:1 against *ALL* adjacent colors.

For WCAG 2.2 the following rules apply:

> - **Minimum area:** The focus indicator area is either:
>
>   - at least as large as the area of a 1 CSS pixel thick perimeter of the unfocused component;
>   - at least as large as a 4 CSS pixels border along the shortest side of the unfocused component, and no thinner than 2 CSS pixels.

Obviously WCAG 2.2 is just a draft but I think the principles are pretty close to final for borders and focus indicators.

You can see the WCAG 2.2+ [understanding doc for contrast (minimum) here](https://w3c.github.io/wcag/understanding/contrast-minimum.html)

#### Internet Explorer(IE) compatibility

The only other thing to consider is compatibility - if you still support IE8 you cannot use [`box-shadow`](https://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow) or [`outline`](https://caniuse.com/outline) - and [quite a few screen reader users are still using IE8](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#browsers) due to software compatibility.

However I would advise a different basic stylesheet for IE8 anyway as otherwise you are stuck in the dark ages! I personally only support back to IE9 as that is painful enough!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! In essence, I got the answer I needed, that box-shadow is fine to use as an alternative to outline.
I tried to keep the example simple, but I'll adjust it to the comments you made regarding contrast. The first version used colors I thought wouldn't take focus away from the outline vs box-shadow topic.

Comment: FYI That is not the standard for SILVER, that is the standard for WCAG 2.x, and this is not linking to the correct document. Silver/WCAG 3.0 is completely different in terms of contrast.

Comment: Rather than post a new answer, I edited this one for correctness. FUTURE: WCAG **3.0** (aka Silver) is taking an entirely different approach, and nothing in this answer is expected to apply. However, WCAG 2.2 will be valid even after Silver is the recommendation.

Comment: I will edit my answer soon, unfortunately somebody has edited the original question so nothing in here makes sense & your edits do not improve that, but you are indeed correct I was obviously sleepy when I wrote this, I have no idea why I was talking about WCAG SILVER. And you are also correct, once again WCAG guidance is unclear as I will not be the only one considering contrast with a border as sufficient under "A focus indicator that is larger than the minimum area may have parts that do not meet the 3:1 contrast ratio, as long as an area equal to the minimum does meet the contrast ratio."

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for pointing out those massive mistakes!

Comment: Hi Graham, Yes the 3:1 & 2px thing has been a point of discussion as in if we need to re-write it... I'm working only on Silver/WCAG 3.0, and not much involved in 2.2, so I'm not sure the current status (I want to say I saw a solution in survey, but I might be thinking of something else). THAT SAID, since WCAG 2.x contrast is generally wrong, the 3:1 for this use case isn't necessarily ideal — the new contrast method for 3.0/Silver is going to specify and deal with these kinds of issues a little differently (in development). Cheers...

Comment: One thing that would be great (if you have influence and input on 3.0) is to have a better way of getting feedback on drafts so that wording ambiguity can be caught early. For example [this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64435051/2702894) was very "tongue-in-cheek" as I know that an input should have a visible label and not a placeholder but it just shows how difficult it is to give a definitive answer and how the guidance is not clear (if there is a piece of guidance that makes it definitive I would love to see it). Is there any way I can get involved as would love to contribute?

Comment: I have fixed the answer I believe, using the key parts from your suggestions, let me know if you still think there are errors etc.

Comment: Hi Graham, I am one of the authors of 3.0, so yes. But you are welcome to interact directly, and in fact I encourage you to do so. The means is via posting an issue in the appropriate GitHub repository. For 2.2 use: https://github.com/w3c/wcag/issues  and for 3.0/Silver use:  https://github.com/w3c/silver/issues  WCAG & W3 is about public involvement. If you see a problem, say so!