# can I use other elements inside the placeholder

Tags: html, css

Can I use other elements inside the placeholder of the input tag?
something like this:

```
    <input placeholder='search for a restaurant, cuisine, or a dish' className='form-control'/>
```

if I Want the placeholder to be bold, can I use something like

```
    <input placeholder='<h1>search for a restaurant, cuisine, or a dish <h1/>' className='form-control'/>
```

will it work? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placeholder font-size bigger than 16px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916387/placeholder-font-size-bigger-than-16px)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour . As you are a new user you can have one. @gratus

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot add foreign child or context Elements *per-se* inside an `input` (like i.e: the pseudo `::before` or `::after`).

Just style the [`::placeholder` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)

```css
::placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="search for a restaurant, cusine, or a dish" class="form-control" />
```